# Rails JavaScript validations on dynamic nested model fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I have a nested model form where the user can create a "project" that can include any number of "tasks" which consist of a taks "name" and "description". These tasks get added dynamically by the user using jQuery.

I want to provide client side validations for the fields in each of these tasks, currently I am using the [livevalidation](http://livevalidation.com/) plugin.

The problem is that the input fields are given a dynamic id based on the current time since thay have to be unique for Rails to do its stuff when the form is submitted.

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Somehow get the javascript validations to accept a wildcard so that every time a task is added, validations can be set against its fields based on the part of its id that does not change.
2. Create the necessary validation javascript inline at the same time that the task is created.

Would the above work? are there any better options? how would I get an element selected from a partial id match into the validator?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  It lets you create validations based on the attribute names instead of their IDs, and you can use the same set of rules for different forms:

```
validation = { rules: { "name": "required", "description": "required" } }
jQuery("#form-1").validate(validation);
jQuery("#form-2").validate(validation);
```

If you want to pass explicit ids you can use a function to generate your rules:

```
function validation_rules(index){
  return {
    rules: {
      "name["+index+"]": "required",
      "description["+index+"]": "required"
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pan, I did actually have a go with this plugin, but was frustrated with the lack of control when positioning the error messages, that's why I used livevalidation.

Comment: You can overwrite the way error messages are positioned using the jQuery plugin's errorPlacement attribute.  This means you can place them anywhere on the page and style them with any CSS classes you want.

Comment: Right, I just tried to implement your solution, but unfortunately Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for requires both the "id" and the "name" to be unique, e.g <input id="project_tasks_attributes_0_name" name="project[tasks_attributes][0][name]"  size="15" type="text" value="task 1" /> Back to the drawing board :-(

Comment: You can implement the arrays without explicitly writing the index: project[task_attributes][][name] that way the first such instance will have index 0 and the second will have index 1 and so on.  Letting HTML take care of these attributes allows you to write general validation rules. If you feel that you mus still use the explicit index you can create the validation rules using a function that takes the explicit index and populates your validation rules using that.